# Значение чекбоксов сохранить в сессию, если в сессии их нет то записать по умолчанию

Tags: php, ajax, сессия

Есть несколько `input` типа `checkbox`

```
<input type="checkbox" id="someide" name="chb[0]" data-target="somedata" class="hidden check-com" disabled>
...................................................................
<input type="checkbox" id="someide" name="chb[5]" data-target="somedata" class="hidden check-com" disabled>
```

Есть отдельный `js`, где обрабатывается логика поведения, который через `ajax` общается с `php`.

Не могу понять, как мне правильно записать значение чекбоксов в сессию, чтобы потом через `ajax` вытащить в `JS`.

Уточню что никаких кнопок `submit` нету

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
session_start();
.....
$_SESSION['checkboxis'] = $_GET['ch'];
```

где то так на php.

можно использовать и storage js

http://javascript.ru/unsorted/storage
подробнее можно сдесь прочитать, я не силён в js думаю коллеги что нибудь напишут в дополнение с примером кода.

Comment: $_GET['ch'] откуда это появится? объект не в форме, он только для управления рендера DOM.

Comment: когда отправишь ajax на сервер с строкой запроса GET или POST без разницы будет.